# Unable to route correctly in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've been looking for awhile and yet to find an answer to why I am routing wrongly from form submit action to my controller, would love to get some help on this please.

**fileUpload.php**

```
<form action="{{route('bulk-uploadFile')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/uploadfile',array('as' => 'bulk-uploadFile', 'uses' => 'UploadFileController@showUploadFile'));
```

**UploadFileController.php**

```
public function showUploadFile(Request $request){
    //code here
}
```

After clicking on upload I get redirect to a page with the message saying, page could not be found with the following url:

```
 http://localhost:8000/%7B%7Broute('bulk-uploadFile')%7D%7D
```

Would appreciate some help on this as I just started on php 2 days ago!

Comment: Can you define `I am routing wrongly`? Are you getting any errors? Something is working not as expected?

Comment: apologies for not being specified, but after pressing upload, i get redirected to a page that says page could not be found

Comment: In my IDE the route call in fileUpload.php is underlined with the message "Unresolved function route()". For all it matters is there a chance I didn't do a necessary import?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you use HTML file. You should have content of fileUpload.html in `fileUpload.blade.php` file otherwise valid url won't be generated and `{{route('bulk-uploadFile')}}` will be just `{{route('bulk-uploadFile')}}` and it won't create valid url

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake, my view file is fileUpload.php. Will having the .blade at the end make a difference?

Comment: changed the file type to blade and it worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

`.blade` is missing e.g. `<file_name>.blade`